# Interact with items on splash screen from "ApplicationEvents.vb"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a Visual Basic program in Visual Studio that has a splash screen with a label and a progress bar. I would like to interact with them using the `ApplicationEvents.vb` file, the one where you can create events to run when the program starts. The problem is that whenever I run the program and try to run the program and interact with these items, I get this error every time.

[image: Visual Studio Program Error]

I understand that the error is caused because I am trying to access a control that is running on another thread, so how can I access this thread in order to make the change to the splash screen that I want?

Comment: click on the link in "Troubleshooting Tips" titled "How To make cross-thread calls to Windows Forms controls" would be a start

Comment: @Plutonix I did, but it doesn't make sense to me. I am still reading through it, so perhaps it will make sense once I am done.

Comment: its not an uncommon question here...http://stackoverflow.com/q/5624033/1070452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this tutorial of mine on how to access controls from worker threads:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads

You can implement methods in your splash screen using those principles and then call those methods from wherever you like.  For instance, here's a method that updates a ProgressBar on a splash screen no matter which thread it's called from:

```
Public Sub IncrementProgress()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf IncrementProgress))
    Else
        Me.ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's how you might call that method:

```
DirectCast(My.Application.SplashScreen, SplashScreen1).IncrementProgress()
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what is going on here.

Comment: That's exactly why I created the thread I linked to: to explain how to create that code step by step.  Did you bother to follow that link and read that thread or did you just figure that the important information would find you so why break a sweat?

Comment: I followed the link, but I read through it only twice and did not fully understand what was going on. I read through it eight more times, and I finally got it to work. Have an upvote and a checkmark for your nice work.

Comment: Hey, only 10 reads is not too bad. ;-) Certainly a lot to do with multi-threading is confusing but, in this case, you don't even really have to understand what's going on.  If you just follow the instructions I provided then you'll end up with code that works.  If you want to be able to write it out in one go then the understanding is required but you can build it up step by step by following my instructions without necessarily understanding why it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've only gotten as far as following directions, but if I read it ten more times, perhaps I will latch on to the understanding of how and why it works.

Comment: For you or anyone else who needs a bit more, that IncrementProgress method I posted basically says _if we are currently executing on a thread other than the UI thread then create a delegate that will cross the thread boundary and call this method again on the UI thread, otherwise update the ProgressBar directly._  That means that the first call will make a second call on the UI thread and the second call will update the UI.

Answer (score -1):

Create Form drag timer and progressbar to windows form properties of timer enabled true .

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim scount As Integer

```
    scount = 0
    scount = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) + 1
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(scount)
    ProgressBar1.Value = scount
    If (scount = 100) Then



        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Me.Hide()

        Form1.Show()
    End If
```