# AcessViolationException was unhandled VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, awesomium

So I have this form that loads a page, and after the page is loaded I want to insert the source into RichTextBox1.Text

However after the page load the program crashes(?) and gives me this error

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Awesomium.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

This is my code and it is worth mentioning that I am using awesomium for this!

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Thread As System.Threading.Thread
Dim html_source_code As String = ""
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Load_Page)
    Thread.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub Load_Page()
    While html_source_code = ""
        If WebControl1.IsDocumentReady Then
            html_source_code = WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.documentElement.outerHTML").ToString()
            RichTextBox1.Text = html_source_code
        End If
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Load_Page)
    Thread.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your first clue...

`Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`

This is a pretty obvious red flag.  You should never use this except perhaps for very specific debugging purposes, and for very good reason.  Given that the remainder of your code is full of illegal cross thread calls, it's no wonder your program is crashing.

Every single line of code you have written that is executed in a worker thread is touching UI components.  You cannot do this.  See this post for examples : [Cross-thread operation not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624033/cross-thread-operation-not-valid)

UI controls are continuously operated on by the main thread of your application.  The main thread must be able to access them to handle their associated events, draw them to the screen, etc.  If another thread is modifying their contents *while* the main thread is attempting to read or write to them then bad things happen.

Consider a text box that the main thread is attempting to draw to the screen.  It obtains a reference to the location of the string that contains the textbox's text and, in the middle of reading the string, another thread modifies the string, invalidating the reference that the main thread is using.  When the main thread tries to read, its existing reference now points to an invalid memory location and, voila, access violation.

In almost all circumstances you should never, ever set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False`.  Leaving it set `True` will raise an exception, but it gives you the opportunity to see where the problematic code is and allows you to correct it.  Setting it `False` simply hides the illegal call, which may or may not fail, and your application will be vulnerable to random, buggy failures when those illegal calls end up causing problems.  Suggest you do some reading about how to write multithreaded .NET applications.  A good start would be here : [StackOverflow Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvb.net%5D%20cross%20thread).

See also : [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: But removing it or setting it to true doesn't make a difference. I don't think that that is what's causing the issue.

Now the last link u sent me includes like 2198734 lines of code which is too much for me to handle in my head! I just want a quick and simple answer.

Comment: @Thomja Setting it to true will throw an exception rather than an access violation.  Your code and your approach is completely wrong - it needs to be entirely re-written.  There *is* no quick and simple answer.  Multithreading is not simple.  Either take the time to understand how it works or write your code without threads.  To teach all of this is way too much for one answer on StackOverflow.  You need to study.

Comment: I suspected that, I followed a youtube tutorial but it was used for simpler things like a counter. Thanks for your advice.